# ActionMailer sending Blank emails, not rendering templates, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I am very new to rails so please forgive me if i am missing something obvious here!

ActionMailer will not send a body to my email. The header comes thru fine, but no body.

There are several similar questions to mine, however none of the solutions work for me, and i have spent 2 days trawling the internet and chasing my tail, all to no avail!

I have Devise running, and that sends its emails fine!

I have come to the conclusion that actionmailer is not rendering my template.

I have simple-private-messages gem running internal mail and in its controller i am sending an email when a user get a message in the app.

Things i have tried so far:

1. using deliver! instead of deliver
2. specifying content_type:, template_path:, template_name: in user_mailer.erb
3. Running a Block in user_mailer to specify template. ie

   ```
   format.html { render 'welcome_email' }
   format.text { render :text => 'welcome_email.txt.erb' })
   ```

This results in error, despite the templates being in the right directory (i think)

```
     ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template user_mailer/welcome_email with {:locale=[:en], :formats=>[:text], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee, :haml]}.
```

1. All possible names prefix's for template ...
       template.html.erb, template.text.html.erb, template.erb
2. Even tried removing 'config.active_support.deprecation = :log' from the enviroment because a post suggested it might be the fix! (Although how, i have no clue)
3. Dropped any params in the mail just in case that was causing the problems!
4. Revered to welcome_email method as per the API, rather than a custom one that i would perfer, just incase Rails convention over configuration had tripped me up!

Have set the ActionMailer Logging, but it seems to show no errors, says the email is sent, but no reference to the template.
The above solutions are the ones i remember, but they have all worked for others, just not for me!
I am at a complete loss at what i have missed!

Thanks in advance for any help! If you need anymore code let me know.

Running 
 rails 3.2.3, 
 Ruby 1.9, 
 ActionMailer 3.2.3

No one seems to post links to the git repo´s on here. Is there a reason for that? More than happy to provide, but no-one else seems to, so won't for now.

Here is some code to help fault find...

user_mailer.rb

```
    class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default :from => "myemail@gmail.com"



       def welcome_email(user)
         @user = user
         @url  = "http://example.com/login"
         mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
       end
    end
```

messages_controller.rb

```
def create
@message = Message.new(params[:message])
@message.sender = @user
@message.recipient = User.find(params[:message][:to])

if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = "Message sent"
  UserMailer.welcome_email(@message.recipient).deliver!
  redirect_to user_messages_path(@user)
else
  render :action => :new
end
```

end

welcome_email.html.erb

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

welcome_email.text.erb

```
Text Text Text!!!
```

log from console server

```
    Sent mail to user@me.com (14517ms)
Date: Thu, 20 Jun 2013 18:13:23 +0200
From: myapp@gmail.com
To: user@me.com
Message-ID: <31c32a237e61c_b73c3ff82f78328e051786@my-app.com.mail>
Subject: Welcome to My Awesome Site
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1/messages
Completed 302 Found in 14674ms (ActiveRecord: 15.3ms)
```

Comment: First, what is the full path of your mailer templates? Should be app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb. Second, 'bundle open devise' and verify that you're doing it exactly as they do it.

Comment: @davidfurber Thanks for the reply. The paths are 'app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb' and 'app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.test.erb'

Comment: In Devise Gem i am a bit lost, i dont understand the ActionMailer Logic. 
         'def devise_mail(record, action, opts={})
           initialize_from_record(record)
           mail headers_for(action, opts)' Which is not the same as i am doing!

Comment: Sorry, should read 'welcome_email.**text**.erb' above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a silly mistake, like i knew it would be! A Git commit pointed it out...

```
create mode 100644 app/views/user_mailer/ welcome_email.html.erb
create mode 100644 app/views/user_mailer/ welcome_email.text.erb
```

Whitespace at the start of the file name, which is really hard to notice in Sublime Text!

So easy to loose 2 days on silly mistakes, But i learned lots trying to figure it out!